# How do I write the rule for this sequence that is neither arithmetic nor geometric as an equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the sequence $3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65,\dots$

I know the rule is multiply by $2$ then subtract one. $3$ times $2$ is $6$ minus $1$ is $5$ and so on. Easy enough.

How do I write the rule for this sequence as an equation?  I know it is neither arithmetic or geometric.

Comment: Hint: $2^{n} = 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...$. Use induction.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000051

Comment: If you are interested in how to find the rule for a sequence there is an interesting section in The Book of Numbers by Conway and Guy https://www.amazon.co.uk/Book-Numbers-John-H-Conway/dp/038797993X

Comment: Solve it as a fifth power polynomial (I joke, but it will give you the exact values given so far...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the sequence recursively as

$$x_0 = 3$$

$$x_n = 2x_{n-1} - 1 $$

To write it non-recursively:

Consider a new sequence

$$3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, ...$$

and your original:

$$3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, ...$$

Taking the difference of the two sequences we have

$$0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, ...$$

which is $g(x) = 2^{x-1} - 1$.

The top sequence is $3 * 2^{x-1}$. Subtracting $3 * 2^{x-1} - (2^{x-1} - 1)$.

Therefore, your function is

$$ f(x) = 2^x + 1$$

Also, note that you could also add $1$ to $2^x$ and get the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can write recursive function like this

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\ 2(f(x-1))-1 ,  & \text{if x>1,} \\[2ex]
3, & \text{if x=1}
\end{cases}$

Comment: I suppose that the OP wants an explicit formula, like $f(n)=2^n+1$.

Comment: You are right. I looked at from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

We are given $$a_{n+1}=2a_n-1\tag1$$

Equivalently, $$a_{n+1}-2a_n=-1\tag2$$

and $$a_n-2a_{n-1}=-1.\tag3$$

Subtracting $(2)-(3)$ yields
$$a_n-3a_n+2a_{n-1}=0\tag4$$

The characteristic equation is $r^2-3r+2=(r-1)(r-2)=0$.

Therefore, the solutions are $a_n=A+B\cdot2^n.$

Can you use the first two elements of the series to solve for $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}-1 \implies a_n - 1 = 2(a_{n-1}-1)$$
Hence $a_n-1$ is a geometric sequence, and
$$a_n-1 = 2^{n-1}(a_1-1) = 2^n \implies a_n = 2^n+1.\blacksquare$$